# Fragment view async update: ImageView not updating but other childs are getting updated in the view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

I have ViewPager which uses Fragments.. fragments contain only a framelayout with ImageView and big TextView as title right now.. each fragment image is getting loaded asynchronously..

My problem is after asynchronous task is done i can see the title of image getting changed with the new value.. but ImageView shows image which is loaded at first time only..

**onCreateView method**

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_sliding, container, false);
    rootView.setId(imgId);
    return rootView;
}
```

When my async loader loads the information

```
    @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<DImage> arg0, DImage arg1) {
    View v = getView();

    ImageView im = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_image);
    im.setImageBitmap(arg1.image);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_image_title);
    tv.setText(arg1.id + "");

}
```

Result obtained is different for all the fragments.. also the textview text is shown differently when i slide the image.. I tried setting image bitmap to null nd then updating with new bitmap.. but it doesn't work.. any clue where i am going wrong??

EDIT : adding XML of the fragment

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"

    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_image_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for hours...+1!  In my case, I can setText on a TextView in a Fragment from a ListFragment by declaring the TextView statically in the "Details" Fragment, but the ImageView's setImageResource can't be statically updated in the same way, and I get a NPE..same issue?

Comment: @whyoz any luck with changing imageView ??

Comment: I'm glad you responded...hopefully this helps you, but my problem was because I had android:tag="@+id/theImageID" which must have happened when I copied and pasted..you will notice that it should be "id" instead of "tag" which is why I was getting an NPE..simple, but it's usually the simple that causes the most problems because it's so easy to overlook...post your XML and that might help.

Comment: have added the XML.. XML looks pretty ok to me.. i don't get ny Null pointers.. no warnings/errors in logcat.. if i add some more text views, they all change when i slide the images.. only the image remains the same..

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue and spent a couple of hours finding the solution. Hope helps others this solution.

I saw that the `Fragment` is going through `onCreateView`, and I only loaded images when the fragment was visible in an `AsyncTask`. And I checked that `onPostExecute` the bitmaps are set to the `ImageView`, but in vain. The `ImageView` only showed the image first time. Even `invalidate()` didn't helped.

After some search I found that `FragmentPagerAdapter` re-instantiates fragments. And for bigger data is recommended to use: `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. It uses less memory and destroys the fragments.

Read more here: 
[FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)